# Remove some files/dir from a repository? TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Basically I have created a repository and did the first commit. But I realized I didn't want to include some files (for example .jpg)

So I have ignored .jpg from the global preference of tortoiseSVN. But I still see this files in the previous commits, is there any command to delete this ignored files from previous commit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, it is a feature. Subversion has the policy that there is no (user) command to delete files from the repository historically. This may be inappropriate at some point in time (e.g. if you have commited password information accidentally), but it ensures that you are able to reference the past state of your repo without it being changed accidentally by others.

If you want to get rid of the files, you should have a look at the admin part of the Subversion red book, especially the part ["Filtering Repository History"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering).

Answer (score 1):

It's not normally a good idea to muck around with the previous commits. Is your goal to remove the files from the repo? For that you can just navigate to them in the repo browser and blow them away (will trigger another commit to execute the deletion). If there is a space concern, I would just delete the repo and restart (I'm inferring that it's pretty new based on your first sentence).